# Confused with a false proof I made

Tags: proof-explanation, systems-of-equations

> Let $x$ and $y$ be numbers satisfying
>   \begin{cases}
> x+2y=4 \\
> 2x + y = 6 \\
> x= y +1
> \end{cases}
>   Find $x$ and  $y$.

$x + 2y = 4$ is equivalent to $x=4-2y$

We substitute $x$ in the second equation

$$
2x+y=6 \\
8-4y+y=6 \\
-3y=-2 \\
y=2/3
$$
But $x =4-2y=4-4/3=8/3$ and we have $x = y +2=2/3+1=5/3$
which gives $y=2/3=5/3$.

WHAT?!

I'm in grade 9 and studying equations with two unknowns and thought about this example in my head and that's confusing me.

Comment: by saying "Let x and y be numbers satisfying..." you assume the existence of such numbers, which happens to be false, thus you can derive all kinds of nonsense (literally all)

Answer (score 3):

What you did proves that the system has no solution. It's just that.

Answer (score 1):

Jose's answer is correct - this system of equations does not have a solution. I thought I would add by giving some more intuition.

Each of the equations you wrote is the equation of a line in the x-y plane. When you take any two lines, unless they are parallel, they must intersect at some point. That point of intersection (x,y) is exactly the solution to the system of the two equations.

The reason (thought of in this way) that your system does not have a solution, is because you have three equations, and the lines they represent do not all intersect at one point. You should find that any two of your three equations will have a solution when put together. All three, however, do not.

Comment: so if I get this in a test what I say, the informations you gave me are false?

Comment: @SelimJeanEllieh, it would be something of a trick question to say "find $x$ and $y$" when those numbers don't exist, but in case you get this question the appropriate answer is "no such $x$ and $y$ exist" (with the reasoning you wrote in your question).